# How to put a condition on a selection field

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-7

I am a beginner in odoo and I am know how to make a selection condition on a field, here is my code:

```
    ETAT_DOSSIER = [
    ('dos_comp','Dossier Complet'),
    ('dos_manq','Dossier Manquant'),
    ]

    def set_etat_dossier(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        val = {}
        for prod in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if prod.casier_judiciare ==True:
               val['etat_dos'] = ETAT_DOSSIER[0][0]
            else:
               val['etat_dos'] = ETAT_DOSSIER[1][0]

    return val

    columns= {
    'etat_dos': fields.selection(ETAT_DOSSIER,string='Etat Dossier')
              }

    defaults = {
    'etat_dos' : ETAT_DOSSIER[1][0],
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make selection field to function field and call a function which you have defined so you set the value of that field as per your function condition.

```
Ex.
columns = {
    'etat_dos': fields.function(set_etat_dossier, string='Method',type='selection', selection=ETAT_DOSSIER)
    }

    def set_etat_dossier(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        val = {}
        for prod in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if prod.casier_judiciare ==True:
                val['etat_dos'] = ETAT_DOSSIER[0][0]
            else:
                val['etat_dos'] = ETAT_DOSSIER[1][0]
```

Comment: thanks my friend  for this suggestion but the function don't return anything

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I write a possible solution for your issue.

```
def _set_etat_dossier(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    retVal = {}
    for prod in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if prod.casier_judiciare == True:
            retVal[ prod.id ] = ('dos_comp','Dossier Complet')
        else:
            retVal[ prod.id ] = ('dos_manq','Dossier Complet'),

    return retVal



columns = {
    'etat_dos': fields.function(_set_etat_dossier,
                                string='Etat Dossier',
                                type='selection',
                                method=True,
                                selection=ETAT_DOSSIER)
}
```